# Cell value dependent Data Validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following sheets, 'Modules'

```
    | A         | B         | C   
--- |--------   |--------   |-----
 1  | Module    | Status    | ... 
 2  | One       | FAIL      | ... 
 3  | Two       | PASS      | ... 
 4  | Three     | PASS      | ... 
 5  | Four      | FAIL      | ...
```

and 'Module Details'

```
    | A                 | B             | C                 
--- |---------------    |-------------  |-------------------
 1  |                   | Module name   | Show Failed (Y/N) 
 2  | Select Module     | ___________   | Y
```

Is it possible to add Data Validation to `'Module Details'!B2` so that it takes `C2` into account?

```
=IF(
    $C$2="Y",
    'Modules'!$A$2:$A$5,
    "?"
)
```

Is it possible to do it formulas or is VBA the only option?

Comment: Do you want to display the contents of `'Modules'!$A$2:$A$5` if `C2` is `Y` ?  What should the behaviour be if C2 is `N`?

Comment: Possible via formula. Have to use name manager also some other tricks.

Comment: @gbavba it should display a subset of `'Modules'!$A$2:$A$5` where `'Modules'!Bn` is `PASS` or is not `FAIL` (both work with this scenario)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using named ranges.
For clarity you can create 3:

```
ModulesAll:         =Modules!$A$2:$A$5
ModulesPassedOnly:  =INDEX(Modules!$A:$A;MATCH("PASS";Modules!$B:$B;0)):INDEX(Modules!$A:$A;MATCH("PASS";Modules!$B:$B;1))
ShowModules:        =IF('Module Details'!$C$2="Y"; ModulesAll; ModulesPassedOnly)
```

Finally you can add Data Validation to cell B2, be choosing for a list and put "=ShowModules" as a source